# Static Property Observers

Tags: ios, swift, properties, static

As usual, this normally works:

```
var someVar = 1{
    didSet{
        callSomeMethod()
    }
}
```

However, when I make the var static then I cant call the method anymore.

```
static var someVar = 1{
    didSet{
        callSomeMethod() // -> gives error
    }
}
```

The error is shown below. Is it not possible to have property observers on static variables? If so, is there an alternative? Somebody please help.

[image]

Comment: can you add where someVar and callSomeMethod are defined? in same class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Initial Setup**

i think you mean this test:

```
class Test {

    var someVar = 1{
        didSet{
            callSomeMethod()
        }
    }

    func callSomeMethod(){
        print("Test")
    }
}

var test = Test()

print(test.someVar)
test.someVar = 2
print(test.someVar)
```

i get result:

```
1
Test
2
```

**Static vars cannot call instance function**

i add a static, then i need to set the function static too:

```
class Test {

    static var someVar = 1{
        didSet{
            callSomeMethod()
        }
    }

    //this need to be static too
    static func callSomeMethod(){
        print("Test")
    }

}

var test = Test()

print(Test.someVar)
Test.someVar = 2
print(Test.someVar)
```

i get result:

```
1
Test
2
```

**Create an Instance to access instance function**

init the class to access the function call (not recommendet):

```
class Test {

    static var someVar = 1{
        didSet{
            // init the class to get a instance function
            Test().callSomeMethod()
        }
    }

    func callSomeMethod(){
        print("Test")
    }

}

var test = Test()

print(Test.someVar)
Test.someVar = 2
print(Test.someVar)
```

i get result:

```
1
Test
2
```

**Function outside**

when the function is outside then it works too

```
class Test {

    static var someVar = 1{
        didSet{
            callSomeMethod()
        }
    }

}

//this need to be outside
func callSomeMethod(){
    print("Test")
}

var test = Test()

print(Test.someVar)
Test.someVar = 2
print(Test.someVar)
```

i get result:

```
1
Test
2
```